# NuGet package reference is in my project references list, but not in the .csproj?

Tags: c#, nuget, mvvm-light, nuget-package

I'm working in a branch that has suddenly stopped behaving.  When I run the application, it crashes because the MvvmLight assembly in the execution folder is 5.4.1, but my assemblies are referencing 5.3.0.

I have found the project that is copying the 5.4.1 library to my output folder, and it's in the project's References folder, but when I go into "Manage NuGet Packages", it's not installed.  If I open the .csproj in my text editor, there isn't a PackageReference anywhere!

How is it possible that VS is showing the lib in References if it's not in the .csproj?  And how can I remove it?  I've read that I should look for an out-of-date packages.config, but there isn't one.  I've also tried to use `Uninstall-Package MvvmLight -ProjectName MyProject`, but it says that it can't find it in the project.

UPDATE - I checked the same source again and now the MvvmLight reference is gone.  Within that project, there aren't any differences between the files.  I tried to delete the .csproj.user and .suo files just to see if that would do anything, and as expected, it doesn't.

While I'd love to just ignore this since I can continue to work with the fresh checkout, I find this extremely strange and would love to figure out how to fix the problem...

Comment: Maybe someone just downloaded the dlls and referenced them directly outside of nuget.

Comment: @mikez There aren't any direct references to the DLLs.  I've grepped and looked over all of the projects in the Solution Explorer.  The MvvmLight reference also has the distictive icon that is used when the package is added via PackageReference, but there isn't a reference in the .csproj.

Comment: Before Nuget, there was project references. Nuget manages packages that it knows about. I'm pretty sure if you inspect the source code for the project file, you will find the DLL is in fact referenced somewhere, just not within the Nuget sections.

Comment: @JuanR I've looked for all of the original signs as well.  I have searched for "mvvm", "galasoft", "5.3", and "5.4" within that csproj, and none of them are there.

Comment: Then it's coming from another project.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way that a reference from ProjectA magically appears in the references of a ProjectB unless it's been manually added.

But there must be something local in another file that's causing this.  I checked out the source again and opened that solution, and the MvvmLight reference isn't there in the project I've been referring to.